# Import CSV file data into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to load my csv file data in SSMS through bulk insert and I have give proper path of my csv file. But still it gives me error of operating system

```
BULK INSERT t1
FROM 'c:\parentField.csv'
WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

The error I get is:

> Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened. Operating system error code 5

Comment: And what *is* said error..?

Comment: Comments like that should go in your question, not the comments. I've [editted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54235924/edit) it in for you. Sounds like, however, that the SQL Server Service account doesn't have access to the location `C:\.`. Have you checked the account's permissions? Personally, however, I would put the file somewhere else other than the root of C anyway; that's probably not a location you want your SQL Server's Service account to have access to.

Comment: its works. i have put the file into another location and its gonna works.Thanks @larnu

Answer (score 0):

Your table must have the same column of csv.

```
DECLARE     @STR_COMMAND NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE     @patch VARCHAR(max)

set @patch = ''/*path to csv*/
SELECT @STR_COMMAND = 'BULK INSERT /*table*/ FROM ''' +@patch+ '''
WITH
(

FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
)'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @STR_COMMAND;
```